# What is the rationale for ICANN delegating multiple gTLDs with minor differences and similar meaning?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, top-level-domains, cctld, icann

On ICANN website there is this FAQ and Answer.

**2.10 If I want to apply for two similar or related TLDs, for example, ".thing" and ".thething" would that be two applications or one? And if two, do I have to pay $185,000 for each?**

> If an applicant applies for .thing and .thething, those would be
> considered two separate applications. (Applicants should note
> carefully that **the application process is currently designed to not
> allow two strings that are "confusingly similar" to each other to both
> be delegated into the DNS** – please refer to the full text of the
> Applicant Guidebook for details.) If both applications were approved,
> they would result in two separate TLDs. Each application will be
> treated individually and there is no discount on application fees
> based upon the filing of multiple applications.

However, there are several gTLDs with very subtle differences already available for public use. For example:

**.fan** and **.fans**

**.gift** and **.gifts**

**.loan** and **.loans**

**.market** and **.markets** and **.marketing**

**.photo** and **.photos**

**.review** and **.reviews**

The above looks more similar to each other than the example **.thing** and **.thething** they gave. There are also some with the **ing** variant, although not as similar as the above.

**.fish** and **.fishing**

**.shop** and **.shopping**

**.host** and **.hosting**

Answer (score 1):

The rationale ? Money.
The gTLD program is a huge cash cow for Icann. For the registries much less. Some are making money, but many others are not thriving because there is not a lot of demand for their "arbitrary strings".

But it should be pointed out that Icann does not roll out new TLD on their own initiative. New extensions are proposed by would-be registries, Icann studies the proposal after payment of the fee, and eventually delegates the extension at the end of the approval process.

The better question would be: why do registries apply for confusing and overlapping extensions. If you want to operate .fan then probably you feel compelled to sponsor .fans as well to cover bases. And probably the same dilemma is facing site owners: if you already run a website under .fan, maybe you will feel "compelled" to register the same in name in .fans for defensive registration purposes. You might even get a "discount" for grouped purchases.

Maybe that's the whole point: get people to register more domain names.

Comment: Seems contradictory: "The gTLD program is a huge cash cow for Icann. For the registries much less." and "But it should be pointed out that Icann does not roll out new TLD on their own initiative. New extensions are proposed by would-be registries".

Comment: "The better question would be: why do registries apply for confusing and overlapping extensions." Probably in part due to the reasons I developed in my answer to the similar question noted above: during the process there was more directions on string confusion and one could have imagined/hoped that "duplicates" or nearly duplicates would have been rules out somehow. But things changes and almost everything was allowed.

Comment: "Maybe that's the whole point: get people to register more domain names." If you take the example of `fan` vs `fans`,  they are not managed by the same registry at all. So I doubt there are a lot of cases, if any, of a single registry applying for multiple duplicates, as it makes no sense for them. But multiple applicants, hence registries, did apply for very similar strings.

Comment: I checked all the example TLDs I posted in the question. In almost all cases the singular and plural version are delegated to different competing registries. The only exception there `market` and `marketing` owned by same registry. Then again `markets` is owned by a different registry. If ICANN was sticking by the statement they made in the FAQ I posted then the duplicates should have been rejected in the evaluation stage, even if its from same registry.